# Can I use a template literal containing a variable as an object key?

Tags: typescript, template-literals

I expected the following code to work, I'm not sure why it doesn't:

```js
interface Person {
  firstName: string
}

const property: 'Name' = 'Name'

const zack: Person = {
  [`first${property}`]: 'Zack'
}
```

Creating `zack` throws an error:

```
Property 'firstName' is missing in type '{ [x: string]: string; }' but required in type 'Person'.
```

Playing around with this even more, any string concatenation seems to be the issue:

```js
type EqualsFirstName = 'firstName'

const value: EqualsFirstName = 'first' + 'Name'
```

That doesn't work either.

Comment: Here's an even simpler example of what I'm referring to in the TypeScript REPL: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAogjgVwIYBsDOAxAlgJzcAOSQFtoBeKAcgDNd8jTKAoJlCYKAN1QQgC5YiVJjqES5KrTxjSMAB7AcSSgDo0KLAGMIACgAMAGigBOAJSt2XHhABMA+MnTZpDCTVGUoAaiqvmbDm4UXgBmeyEnUVcoCgADABIAb3dpSgBfV1iWJiA

Comment: FYI, here is an ongoing issue on the TypeScript repo regarding the implementation of this feature: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754#issuecomment-511460517

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler is rather strict in evaluating mapped types. There are quite a few things that don't work well with them and this is one of them. It works when you assert the type:

```
const zack: Person = {
    [`first${property}` as 'firstName']: 'Zack'
}
```

This is not really helpful though as the following code shows, which will also compile fine, but fail miserably at runtime:

```
const property: 'Foo' = 'Foo'

const zack: Person = {
  [`first${property}` as 'firstName']: 'Zack'
}
```

The other (somewhat clumsy) option is to assert the type `Person` with `as` (and go through an assertion to `unknown` first):

```
const zack = {
  [`first${property}`]: 'Zack'
} as unknown as Person
```

Like in the first option, this won't help you at runtime if the assertion is invalid.

I would suggest you try to do without this notation and choose a more "TS compiler friendly" way. This is a quite unusual construct that technically is valid, but that you'd rather avoid in practice.

Comment: Thank you for the potential approaches. For anyone tracking this, there is ongoing discussion on the TypeScript repo regarding how to support concatenated strings: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754#issuecomment-511460517

Answer (score 0):

This hack might work out

```
interface Person {
  firstName: string
}

const property: 'Name' = 'Name'
type EqualsFirstName = 'firstName'

const zack: Person = {
  [`first${property}` as EqualsFirstName]: 'Zack'
}
```